# python+numpy: why does numpy.log throw an attribute error if its operand is too big?

Tags: python, numpy

Running

```
np.log(math.factorial(21))
```

throws an `AttributeError: log`. Why is that? I could imagine a `ValueError`, or some sort of `UseYourHighSchoolMathsError`, but why the attribute error?

Comment: I suppose NumPy first tries to convert the argument to one of its scalar types and then tries to access some NumPy-specific attribute.  `math.factorial(21)` excedes the size of `numpy.uint64`, so it can't be converted to a NumPy scalar.  Of course NumPy *should* throw a `ValueError`!

Comment: See also [AttributeError in python/numpy when constructing function for certain values](/questions/18833639/attributeerror-in-python-numpy-when-constructing-function-for-certain-values)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The result of `math.factorial(21)` is a Python long. numpy cannot convert it to one of its numeric types, so it leaves it as `dtype=object`. The way that unary ufuncs work for object arrays is that they simply try to call a method of the same name on the object. E.g.

```
np.log(np.array([x], dtype=object)) <-> np.array([x.log()], dtype=object)
```

Since there is no `.log()` method on a Python long, you get the `AttributeError`.

Comment: Wow, this explains a lot of things

Answer (score 5):

Prefer the `math.log()` function, that does the job even on long integers.