# Is this the wrong error message - AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'log2'?

Tags: python, numpy

I guess this has to do with integer type overflow. But why the strange error message?

```
In [36]: import numpy as np

In [37]: np.log2(2**63)
Out[37]: 63.0

In [38]: np.log2(2**64)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-38-f1b1c814f08c>", line 1, in <module>
    np.log2(2**64)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'log2'
```

Why does it say "has no attribute" and not something like "integer overflow"? Or did I misunderstood the reason for the error? I can see how this error message can be very confusing in helping to find where a problem is.

Comment: @cdrake Sorry for not being clear on 'np' being the common name for the numpy module. I've edited the question to include the appropriate import command. 2**64 is indeed an int. But why say that it  has no attribute and not that is 'too large' for the np.log2 function?

Comment: Trivially reproducible; demo http://ideone.com/CSk6H1 ... Sigh, people could check this before posting speculative comments.

Comment: I tested the code on Python 2.7 and 3.5 both interactively and from a script.  It worked fine for me, then I realised I had only done the `2**63`, it is the `2**64` which upsets it.  Shows I should read the error message, apologies.

Comment: The error message is completely false, a `type(np)`, and `np.log2(2**63)` after the error shows that `np` is not an int.  Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833639/attributeerror-in-python-numpy-when-constructing-function-for-certain-values

Comment: Tested on python 2.7 and the error message gives `long` instead of `int`.  Changed my search parameters and found this which has a explanation (but not a fix):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032781/pythonnumpy-why-does-numpy-log-throw-an-attribute-error-if-its-operand-is-too

Comment: So the error occurs inside `np.log2`.  It has calculated 2*64, and is now seeking its `log2` method.  The `int` in the message refers to that large number, not `np`.  In an ideal world such a message would have been caught and rephrased.  But since it is uncommon or unexpected the `numpy` implementation has not taken that step.

Comment: In Python3 it shows as `int` - because there isn't a separate `long` type.  But it's the same issue, trying to apply the `numpy` function to a number that is too large to represent as `np.int64`.  `2.**64` runs fine.  And `math.log2` is ok as well.